# Implementing Vpc peering in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I was trying to demonstrate VPC peering in GCP. I followed the below steps;

**Setup1 :**

I logged into GCP admin user account and I have created VPC in custom mode and added a subnet in the us-central region under one project. Than I have set the firewall rule to allow ssh and tcp. Than I created a VM instance in the same `us-central` region also selected this custom VPC and subnet in networking option. Than I tried to ssh into that VM and tried to ping from cloud shell. Both are working fine.

**Setup2:**

I logged into GCP user account which is added as a service account user by admin (previously used admin account). In that I created VPC in custom mode and added a subnet in the `asia-east` region under another project. Than I created a VM instance in the same asia-east region also selected this custom VPC and subnet in networking. Then I have set the firewall rule to allow ssh and tcp. Then I tried to ssh into that VM and tried to ping from cloud shell. Both are working fine.

Both VPC's haveDynamic routing mode set as Regional.

Than I tried to ping `us-central` machine from `asia-east` machine and also `asia-east` machine from `us-central` machine.

My expectation was, it won't work as it uses two different VPC which has subnet in two different region. So i can implement VPC peering to make it possible. But unfortunately it is working. I just tried to demonstrate VPC peering concept.

Can anyone suggest me what i missed in it?

===============================================================

**UPDATE**

```
gcloud compute networks describe  vpc1
autoCreateSubnetworks: false
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-03T04:08:24.491-07:00'
description: ''
id: '8530504402595724487'
kind: compute#network
mtu: 1460
name: my-vpc
routingConfig:
  routingMode: REGIONAL
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/global/networks/my-vpc
subnetworks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/my-subnet
x_gcloud_bgp_routing_mode: REGIONAL
x_gcloud_subnet_mode: CUSTOM


gcloud compute networks describe  vpc2

autoCreateSubnetworks: false
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-03T04:56:02.154-07:00'
description: ''
id: '8965341541776208829'
kind: compute#network
mtu: 1460
name: my-project2-vpc
routingConfig:
  routingMode: REGIONAL
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/global/networks/my-project2-vpc
subnetworks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/asia-subnet
x_gcloud_bgp_routing_mode: REGIONAL
x_gcloud_subnet_mode: CUSTOM
```

Comment: Can you please run `gcloud compute networks describe vpc-name` on both VPC's and update your question with the details. Please remove all sensitive info from the output.

Comment: How many network interfaces do your VM's have ? If more than 1 please provide their configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my head around it - I couldn't reproduce your issue because I was missing firewall rules (I assumed GCP will create them but when you're creating custom networks no rules are created by default). I had to allow SSH (TCP port 22 and ICMP protocol to be allowed) traffic manually and then everything started working as you described.

**Communication between the networks is possible due to the fact, that the VM's (by default) get public IP's and are accessible for every machine connected to the internet.** You didn't provide that information so I assumed that you didn't change any networking setting while creating test VM's - thus created VM's with public IP's.

But if you create the VM's with only internal IP's - they won't be able to communicate to VM's from different VPC's without [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering). Any communication between the networks (regardless of the region they are in) is impossible in such cases.

Comment: yes..this makes sense..Thank you :)